# BeautifulSoup not reading entire HTML obtained by requests

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a table of sporting statistics presented as HTML using the BeautifulSoup and requests libraries.  I am running both of them on Python 3.5.  I seem to be successfully obtaining the HTML via requests because when I display `r.content`, the full HTML of the website I am trying to scrape is displayed.  However, when I pass this to BeautifulSoup, BeautifulSoup drops the bulk of the HTML which are the tables of statistics themselves.

If you take a look at the [website](http://afltables.com/afl/stats/games/2015/031420150402.html) in question, the HTML from "Scoring Progression" onward is dropped.

I think the problem relates to the pieces of HTML which are included between brackets ('[' and ']') but I have not been able to develop a workaround.  I have tried the html, lxml and html5lib parsers for BeautifulSoup, to no avail.  I have also tried providing 'User-Agent' headers and that did not work either.

My code is as below.  For brevity's sake I have not included the output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://afltables.com/afl/stats/games/2015/031420150402.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

print(soup)
```

Comment: Works for me using `lxml` or even leaving parser out (defaults to `lxml`).

Comment: @roadrunner66 BeautifulSoup warns if you omit the parser. _UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently._

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a different parser and it seemed to work; just the default html parser.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

url = 'http://afltables.com/afl/stats/games/2015/031420150402.html'
client = uReq(url)  # grabs the page
soup = BeautifulSoup(client.read(), 'html.parser')  # using the default html parser
tables = soup.find_all('table')  # gets all the tables
print(tables[7])  # scoring progression table, the 8th's table
```

Though if you had tried something like "soup.table" without having used "find_all" clause first, it would seem like it dropped the other tables since it only returns the first table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this has definitely gotten me closer to a solution.  The only thing is when I print `tables`, I do not get the nested tree of elements that BeautifulSoup is supposed to display as.

I also am still not getting the entirety of the HTML in `soup`.  Can I ask, did you compare the HTML printed from `soup` with the actual page source?  I think I have not done a good job in expressing what is missing when I produce soup.

I also wonder now whether the problem is not with BeautifulSoup, but how I am using requests seeing as you got a different result from urllib?

Comment: Yes I would go wtih urllib since that is the most well supported HTTP request package. If you are on Python 3, use urllib. If you are on Python 2, use urllib2. Also, yes I did compare the actual HTML document to my soup and my soup successfully souped all of it.